# PowerPoint Morph Transition - What makes up an slide-overarching object morph pair?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

When using the [PowerPoint Morph Transition](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-morph-transition-in-powerpoint-8dd1c7b2-b935-44f5-a74c-741d8d9244ea), I want a specific object to **not** translate or rotate when transitioning from one slide to the next but just fade out and fade in (as any other non-morphed object does).

1. How can I accomplish this?
2. And more generally: What criteria does an object have to fulfill for PowerPoint to match it as a "morphing partner" of another object on another slide? (It can't be the name - I checked that.)

Answer (score 0):

Rightclick the shape on either of the slides, choose Edit Points. Add a new point anywhere on the shape. PowerPoint will no longer morph that shape.

OR

Select the shape, rightclick and choose COPY.
Then on the home tab, click the triangle beneath PASTE and choose Paste Special, then paste as an Enhanced Metafile.